# How to convert Google map embed API's iframe src from the Web to show in a map in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-embed

I have a Website which its content consists of Google map embed iframe to show a specific place. The src of the iframe looks like `https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3908.7524594404968!2d104.91879246446418!3d11.569595197216245!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3109514136061e13%3A0xa6a91c61221f6533!2z4Z6V4Z-S4Z6f4Z624Z6a4oCL4Z6S4Z-G4oCL4Z6Q4Z-S4Z6Y4Z64LCDhnprhnrbhnofhnpLhnrbhnpPhnrjigIvhnpfhn5LhnpPhn4bhnpbhn4Hhnok!5e0!3m2!1skm!2skh!4v1502613617980`.

I am now developing an Android app to show this kind of this content. Instead of showing this iframe map in a WebView, how can I get latitude, longitude, and place ID from that URL? And how to display it using Google map sdk for Android?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution/replacement for this, I am kind of looking for something similar.

Comment: @AbdulMueed Not yet.